# Como Salvar uma Imagem no banco de dados

Tags: android, banco-de-dados

Olá, queria saber se tem como salvar uma imagem no banco de dados e mostrar em uma listview . Se tiver como queria saber ou se não tem como salvar uma imagem no banco de dados , como posso fazer pra chamar uma imagem diferente para cada row ....

Comment: salva a referencia aonde a imagem está localizada, se não https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659835/how-to-store-image-in-sql-server-database-tables-column

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É possível salvar imagens no banco de dados convertendo elas para um array de bytes (`byte[]`) e armazená-las como um BLOB no banco, mas por experiência própria não é performático, pois essa conversão/desconversão constante, por conta do adapter da ListView, deixou a UI extremamente lenta quando implementei dessa forma.

O ideal é guardar a referência das imagens no banco  e depois usar essas referências para acessar as imagens salvas localmente. Bibliotecas como o Picasso ou Glide já fazem um cache local.